# Why is Pyspark/Snowflake insensitive to underscores in column names?

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Working in  Python 3.7 and pyspark 3.2.0, we're writing out a PySpark dataframe to a Snowflake table using the following statement, where mode usually equals 'append'.

```
df.write \
    .format('snowflake') \
    .option('dbtable', table_name) \
    .options(**sf_configs) \
    .mode(mode)\
    .save()
```

We've made the surprising discovery that this write can be insensitive to underscores in column names -- specifically, a dataframe with the column "RUN_ID" is successfully written out to a table with the column "RUNID" in Snowflake, with the column mapping accordingly.  We're curious why this is so (I'm in particular wondering if the pathway runs through a LIKE statement somewhere, or if there's something interesting in the Snowflake table definition) and looking for documentation of this behavior (assuming that it's a feature, not a bug.)

Comment: What will happen if extending the config with `sf_configs += ("keep_column_case"->"on")`?

Comment: According to the docs, the snowflake connector defaults to using column order instead of name, see parameter `column_mapping`: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#label-spark-options

Comment: Of course... got caught down in the trees and missed the forest.  If you'll turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#label-spark-options), the snowflake connector defaults to using column order instead of name, see parameter `column_mapping`.

> The connector must map columns from the Spark data frame to the Snowflake table. This can be done based on column names (regardless of
> order), or based on column order (i.e. the first column in the data
> frame is mapped to the first column in the table, regardless of column
> name).
>
> By default, the mapping is done based on order. You can override that by setting this parameter to name, which tells the connector to
> map columns based on column names. (The name mapping is
> case-insensitive.)